# Configure NetBeans Formatter

Tags: angularjs, netbeans

I'm having a problem with netbeans code formatter when I use AngularJS, specially in one case.

When I use this rule: `ng-class="(status.index >= $index)?'btn-success':'btn-default'"` and I proceed the code format (alt+shift+F) it changes to `ng-class="(status.index >= $index)?'btn-success':'btn - default'"` (with spaces) and bug the functionality of the class.

The only way to I fix this is changing the way I do the `ng-class`or there is any way to I fix this rule in NetBeans configurations?

I appreciate your time reading this, ty all

Comment: Hi! Did You fix the issue? Which version are/were You using?

Comment: Hi not at all, I'm justing taking care of not auto-format, my netbeans is the 8.1

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to install a new theme.

I installed the [atom font and colors](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/58808/atom-fonts-e-colors-theme), which solved the problem. This means that it could be solved only by configuring the IDE, although I don't exactly know what.

I hope this can help You.

Comment: Good! It is actually a good sign, that it have a simple solution, but I can't propose it to all my collages...